# How to use Grid and create this?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms

i would like to create a view like this : 
[image]

. Where `Contact1`, `Contact2` are `models` and `ListView`is a list of these models.
Now i have code like this but i dont get the desired output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="KiaiDay.Pages.ConviteEmailPage"
             NavigationPage.TitleView="Convive por email"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="True"
             NavigationPage.BackButtonTitle="Voltar"
             BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <ActivityIndicator x:Name="indicador" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,100,100" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" Color="Blue"/>
            <StackLayout>
                <ListView  x:Name="ListaContactos">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Imagem}"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Nome}"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Email}"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Numero}"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: use a CollectionView - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview

Comment: Keep in mind `CollectionView` is still in preview in XF 3.6, but from my usage, it has been pretty solid. Also, if you have only a small collection of set contacts that don't change you could use a `FlexLayout` inside a `ScrollView instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jason said, you can use [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview#populating-a-collectionview-with-data) to do it.However,you should note that:

> The `CollectionView` is currently an early preview, and lacks much of its planned functionality. In addition, the API will change as the implementation is completed.

And `CollectionView` is available in **Xamarin.Forms 4.0-pre1**.

If no problem with version, using code as follow:(**Update: Adding Frame to code**)

```
<StackLayout Margin="20,35,20,20">
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}" >
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
           <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                            Span="2" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout Padding="10">
                <Frame BackgroundColor="LightGray"
                       OutlineColor="Black"
                       CornerRadius="10">
                <Grid Padding="5" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="120">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" 
                           Text="{Binding Name}" 
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
                    <Image Grid.Row="1" 
                           Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" 
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           HeightRequest="60" 
                           WidthRequest="60" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="2" 
                           Text="{Binding Location}"
                           LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                           FontAttributes="Italic" 
                           VerticalOptions="End" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="3" 
                           Text="{Binding Details}"
                           LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                           FontAttributes="Italic" 
                           VerticalOptions="End" />
                </Grid>
                </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

Refer to [official sample](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/forms40/UserInterface/CollectionViewDemos/) , binding source:

```
BindingContext = new MonkeysViewModel();
```

Here is the capture image of app.

[image]

Comment: It's also possible to insert a rounded box and have all the elements inside of it ?

Comment: @Kelve Yeah,it's sure can do that.Adding `Frame`,and all elements inside of it can do that.I will update answer.